# ACR122U emulate JIS 9319-4 tag instead of ISO 14443-4 tag when keep phone on the reader

Tags: android, nfc, emulation, cardreader, acr122

I have a strange problem. When i emulate a tag with the ACR122U it normally emulate a ISO 14443-4 (NfcA) tag. This always works in the following sequence:

- Start emulating with `tgInitAsTarget`
- Phone on the reader
- Transaction succesfull
- Phone off the reader

But in this sequence below the emulated tag is recognized as a JIS 9319-4 tag

- Start emulating with `tgInitAsTarget`
- Put phone on the reader
- Transaction error
- Retransmit `tgInitAsTarget`
- Not a ISO 14443-4 tag anymore
- Phone off the reader

So if i keep my phone on the reader and start another `tgInitAsTarget` it doesn't recognize the tag correcly. Why is this?

Regards,

Comment: I can confirm that this is a known problem and seems to be related to how the PN532 NFC chip inside the ACR122U performs card emulation. Unfortunately we did not find a solution to this so far.